# RxJava merge subscriber gets results only from first observable

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to understand how rxjava merge works. So here is simple code that should merge results from 2 observables and emit to subscriber

```
    Observable.merge(getObservable(), getTimedObservable())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                    @Override public void call(final String s) {
                        Log.i("test", s);
                    }
                });

    private Observable<String> getTimedObservable() {
        return Observable.interval(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map(new Func1<Long, String>() {
                    @Override public String call(final Long aLong) {
                        Log.i("test", "tick thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                        return String.valueOf(aLong);
                    }
                });
    }

    public Observable<String> getObservable() {
        return  Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override public void call(final Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                try {
                    Log.i("test", "simple observable thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        subscriber.onNext(String.valueOf(i * 100));
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I was expected that merged result in subscriber would be like

> 100 0 1 200 2 300 4 5 400

or something like that, however, the actual result is:

```
 test: simple observable thread: 257 
test: 100
test: 200
test: 300
test: 400
test: 500
test: 600
test: 700
test: 800
test: 900
test: 1000
test: tick thread: 254
test: 0
test: tick thread: 254
test: 1
test: tick thread: 254
test: 2
test: tick thread: 254
test: 3
test: tick thread: 254
test: 4
test: tick thread: 254
test: 5
test: tick thread: 254
test: 6
test: tick thread: 254
test: 7
test: tick thread: 254
test: 8
test: tick thread: 254
test: 9
test: tick thread: 254
test: 10
test: tick thread: 254
test: 11
test: tick thread: 254
test: 12
test: tick thread: 254
test: 13
```

It looks like Thread.sleep in first Observable blocks emitting in second observable, but I don't understand how. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

merge will subscribe to both observables at the same time. The observable which will be subscribed first, will produce values on calling thread. Because the calling thread is blocked by observable1, observable2 can not produces values. SubscribeOn will only say where the subscription will happen. Lets say observable starts producing values on main-1. Every value downstreams will be on the same thread. No concurrency is happening.

If you want to achive concurrency, you have to say for each observable, where the subscription has to happen. So lets say we have Observables.merge with two observables. Observable1 and Observable2 have subscribeOn with some Threadpool. Each observable will generate values on given thread of subscribeOn. You achieved concurrency.

Plase have a look at the edited output at:

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    Subscription subscribe = Observable.merge(getObservable(), getTimedObservable())
            //.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> {

                System.out.println("subscription " + s);
                //Log.i("test", s);
            });


    Thread.sleep(5_000);
}

private Observable<String> getTimedObservable() {
    return Observable.interval(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(aLong -> {
                System.out.println("getTimedObservable: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                //Log.i("test", "tick thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                return String.valueOf(aLong);
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}

private Observable<String> getObservable() {
    return Observable.<String>create(subscriber -> {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("getObservable: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                subscriber.onNext(String.valueOf(i * 100));
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Comment: so you want to say, that no matter I have written `  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, merge subscribes to observables on the same thread? why are thread ids different then in observables?

Comment: Different thread because the default subscribeOn-scheduler for interval is the computational-threadpool from RxJava. It has a default scheduler, so now deadlock would arise if the value production would happen on the same thread as the calling one. getObservable has noe default scheduler, so it will be subscribed on the  io-scheduler as given with subscribeOn. Because it its subscribed, it will start producing values on the io-threadpool. The calling thread is blocked until the Observable.create stops producing. If you switch getObservable with getTimedObservable, you will get concurrency

Answer (score 1):

RxJava by default is not multithreaded, and everything runs on the same thread. If you want multithreading, you need to use a scheduler.

Add an `.subscribe(Subscribers.io())` at the end of `getObservable()`.

Answer (score 0):

[merge](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) subscribes to two at once observables, first observable1 second observable2, every observables should work on its own thread `subscribeOn`, as a result, we receive data from two observables, depending on who sends the data observable1 or observable2

```
val observable1 = Observable.create<Int> {
    it.onNext(1)
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    it.onNext(2)
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

val observable2 = Observable.create<Int> {
    it.onNext(3)
    it.onNext(4)
    Thread.sleep(1500)
    it.onNext(5)
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

observable1.mergeWith(observable2).subscribe {}
```

result
1, 3, 4, 2, 5